# SQL TRY-CATCH and the missing columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, try-catch

I have the following (SQL Server 2005)

```
DECLARE @L_ID_FOO_BAR INT

BEGIN TRY
  SELECT @L_ID_FOO_BAR = IDFOO 
  FROM BAR
  WHERE IDFOO = 5
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  SELECT @L_ID_FOO_BAR = NULL
END CATCH
```

in the BAR table I could have (on old databases) or not (in some more recennt databases) the IDFOO column. So, for the missing IDFOO column I'd like to leave @L_ID_FOO_BAR = NULL, in case if that column exists select the respective IDFOO.

However, when executing the script on bases without that column I obtain:

> Invalid column name: 'IDFOO'

I already surrounded the script with

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SYSCOLUMNS 
WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID('BAR') AND NAME = 'IDFOO')
```

but this didn't help, it complains about the invalid column...

Questions
a) **What to do** to make work this script on both databases, with or without that column?
b) **Why** does try-catch not hide the invalid column error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Question (b) is easier to answer - what you are facing there is a compile-time check, which trumps TRY-CATCH which work at run-time.

For (a)

```
DECLARE @L_ID_FOO_BAR INT;
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
  SELECT @L_ID_FOO_BAR = IDFOO 
  FROM BAR
  WHERE IDFOO = 5';

BEGIN TRY
  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@L_ID_FOO_BAR INT output', @L_ID_FOO_BAR output;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  SELECT @L_ID_FOO_BAR = NULL -- redundant? it starts with NULL
END CATCH
```

Comment: little fix: `DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) *SET @SQL=...*`

Comment: egads.. 2005. How did I miss that :)

Answer (score 2):

I would check `syscolumns` or `information_schema` for the existence of the column, then build a dynamic sql query that you then execute with `sp_executesql` with or without the missing column.

Comment: Create a view on the old databases that mimics the missing field then.