# Cannot catch SQL Server SP errors that bypass try..catch in code

Tags: sql-server, vba, adodb

I have a SQL Server Stored Procedure. If I put a try block around the code it only catches certain errors and instead just pushes some errors to the SSMS Messages window. I believe the documentation ([TryCatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) says certain errors are not caught by the try..catch block (e.g. selecting from a non-existent table)

An example in my case is selecting columns that do not exist via a synonym which sends this to the Messages output pane:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   dbo.TestSP, Line 185 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   Invalid column name 'InvalidColumn'.

However, I am running the SP from code not SSMS and get no errors or exceptions returned.

Specifically, my Command Execute method simply returns without raising an exception, the return value is an empty value, and so I have absolutely no idea what the error is for logging or reporting to the user. I have also tried removing the try block completely with the same results.

I am using old school ADODB in VBA, but the same principle will apply to .Net I have looked at the Command object properties and there doesn't seem to be much there and the State returned is 0.

Is there any way to trap or find these errors somewhere in my Command or Connection objects so I can log them other than simply saying 'unknown error'?

As an example, my Stored Procedure is as follows and the select statement having an invalid column raises an error as shown above and does not raise an error.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestSP]
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 BEGIN TRY
    declare @returnCode int;
    If object_id('syn_xxx','SN') is not null drop synonym syn_xxx
    exec('create synonym syn_xxx for sometable')
    SELECT TOP 1 InvalidColumn from syn_xxx
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
     set @returnCode=ERROR_NUMBER()
 END CATCH
 return @returnCode
END
```

My code is VBA and as follows. The Errors collection contains nothing, the return value is an empty string.

```
Dim conn_ As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Set conn_ = New ADODB.Connection
conn_.Open dsn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "TestSP"
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn_
cmd.Execute
```

Comment: No one can debug code that cannot be seen. Post your vba code.

Comment: No, the same principle definitely does not apply to .NET. If an error is raised on the connection, it will be translated to a `SqlException`, with full details. If your `CATCH` does not rethrow the error that won't happen, but as long as executing it in SSMS gives you an error (in red, so not a message), and all other things remain equal, so will running it as a `SqlCommand`.

Comment: the sql error is a provider error and it should be "logged" in the Errors collection of the connection:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/errors-collection-ado

Comment: @SMor I have added code, but as detailed in the original post, it's kind of irrelevant, simply the stored procedure is failing on a select but is excluded from TRY...CATCH when ran manually (as per Microsoft documentation) but I cannot find any means of getting at what is displayed in ssms when ran in code.

The errors collection does not contain the fault either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816539/sql-try-catch-and-the-missing-columns . Try catch will pick up runtime exceptions, not compile time ones. I know you're trying to catch them in VBA, but altering your SQL may help.

Comment: Link from @lptr contains [ADO error handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/error-handling?view=sql-server-ver15) and code [handling-errors-in-vbscript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/handling-errors-in-vbscript?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

What provider are you using in dsn ?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim errLoop As ADODB.Error
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim StrTmp As String


    'On Error GoTo AdoError
    On Error Resume Next

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;" _
             & "Server=(local);" _
             & "Database=master;" _
             & "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    con.Open

    cmd.ActiveConnection = con
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "TestSP"
    cmd.Execute

    MsgBox ("number of errors after procedure 'testproc'  --- " & con.Errors.Count)

    If con.Errors.Count > 0 Then

        i = 1

        ' Process
        StrTmp = StrTmp & vbCrLf & "VB Error # " & Str(Err.Number)
        StrTmp = StrTmp & vbCrLf & "   Generated by " & Err.Source
        StrTmp = StrTmp & vbCrLf & "   Description  " & Err.Description

        ' Enumerate Errors collection and display properties of
        ' each Error object.

        For Each errLoop In con.Errors
            With errLoop
                StrTmp = StrTmp & vbCrLf & "Error #" & i & ":"
                StrTmp = StrTmp & vbCrLf & "   ADO Error   #" & .Number
                StrTmp = StrTmp & vbCrLf & "   Description  " & .Description
                StrTmp = StrTmp & vbCrLf & "   Source       " & .Source
                i = i + 1
            End With
        Next

        MsgBox (StrTmp)

    End If

    cmd.CommandText = "select 10 as test"
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmd.Execute
    MsgBox ("number of errors after 'select 10 as test'  --- " & con.Errors.Count)


    ' Close all open objects.
    If con.State = adStateOpen Then
        con.Close
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: data source=server;initial catalog=db;Provider=SQLOLEDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;

i get nothing back from the SP other than any RAISERROR lines I add as comments prior to it failing

Comment: after changing the connection string to use oledb, the code in the answer above returns : `Error #1: ADO Error   #-2147217900 Description  Invalid column name 'InvalidColumn'. Source Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.